# How to dispute deleted post

Tags: support, deleted-questions, moderation

I posted a question on stackoverflow that was deleted by a moderator. As a programmer for almost 15 years now, I think my question was an entirely valid and rather important question actually. Is there any way to dispute what moderators are doing?

Comment: Link to the question?

Comment: Sure, flag it choose Other and explain. If you get no response for whole day, come here for more support. (You can see your flag status by clicking the "helpful flags" link in your profile page)

Comment: Worth to mention the existence of "meta effect" - you'll get much attention to your question and it's not always a good thing.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I would say wait until the flag gets declined (if the reason doesn't tell you enough) to post on meta, whenever that happens to be, rather than posting here before the flag has even been handled, even if it does take a day

Comment: @Servy full day is reasonable time. I once flagged as Other and it took two weeks (!) to be handled. It wasn't important so I didn't mind,  but something like this is more important.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Sure, that that means that the moderator(s) haven't had a chance to look into it.  If there are flags going unhandled it means that they don't have the time to deal with them.  Posting on meta is just trying to cut to the front of the line; if they don't have enough time, they don't have enough time.  You posting on meta is time they could have been spent handling even older flags.

Comment: @Servy I disagree. According to you, the [meta-tag:support] is not relevant. Its purpose is to give support exactly on such cases. And asking users to wait weeks before asking on Meta is not reasonable.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The majority of what "support" covers can be answered by non-moderators.  For those cases that *do* need to be answered by a moderator, one should be flagging.  If the flag queue is constantly taking 2 weeks for flags to be handled then that's a separate problem that likely means changing mods' workflows or hiring new mods.  Taking up *more* of their time by just making more requests makes the problem of an overwhelmed queue *worse*, not better.

Comment: @ioplex: the way you dispute a deleted post is either to flag it, or to bring the topic here. But if you bring it here, you need to post a link to the post and explain why you think it should be undeleted. (Your X years of experience as a programmer are entirely irrelevant.)

Comment: I flagged it but how do I see results? I had to use google just to find the post. It does not appear in my Questions.

Comment: @ioplex from my first comment: You can see your flag status by clicking the "helpful flags" link in your profile page. If you don't see such link just [follow this direct link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1023009). (No worry it's Page Not Found for all others)

Comment: @Mat My question (this question) is technically unrelated to the actual content of my stackoverflow post. I am simply asking how someone should go about disputing a moderator's actions and I believe I am qualified to take that action because I have 15 years of experience programming.

Comment: Regarding not appearing in the questions tab, you have link "deleted recent questions" in there, it should show you that question.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard Ok. Thanks. All of this jargon is foreign to me. I will check "helpful flags".

Comment: Again, your years of experience as a programmer is completely irrelevant to what happens to your posts here. We don't care about who posts what, we care about the posts. You've already found the place to log your "complaints"/questions. It's here.

Comment: @Mat is correct, even if Jon Skeet will post off topic question it will get closed and deleted. (not sure about downvoted :))

Comment: It is so ironic that this question is being "moderated" down.

Comment: @ioplex downvotes on meta are more often than not for a different purpose than on the other sites.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Answer (score 13):

Here's a link to your question for those who can see it: [Download JDK 5 without Oracle Web Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897278/download-jdk-5-without-oracle-web-account)

Your question was closed for the following reason.

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Not only are you asking us to help you find a tool, which is off-topic, you *already know* the proper place to download that tool, and you want someone to tell you another place you can get it.

Now that people here on Meta can see which question you're talking about, they can discuss whether or not it should be undeleted/reopened.  I think you'd need to reformulate the question entirely in order for that to happen, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: And there's still [a webcache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19897278%2Fdownload-jdk-5-without-oracle-web-account&rlz=1C1FDUM_enCH472CH472&oq=cache%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19897278%2Fdownload-jdk-5-without-oracle-web-account&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1564j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) for those interested.

Comment: I did not ask how to find a tool. I asked how to cross-compile java libs without providing Oracle with my full identity, company name, job title, address and business phone number. Anyone who maintains a serious Java lib needs to do this if they want their product to work with older versions of Oracles runtimes. But I agree it would probably generate opinionated answers. Or at least it should. I actually don't have a problem with that restriction in your site. Maybe this question would be better for Slashdot. It's your website.

Comment: @ioplex Isn't java backwards compatible by default. What you seem to want is the old version to check that you've not used any new features. And that's a request for a download location recommendation (also isn't the real answer; give oracle fake details and a throw away email address, but don't tell anyone I told you)